# Disable 'Allow height to increase' option of textbox properties in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS report which use a background image. I need data appears in a fixed position box in image. There are 2 boxes that need to insert table to.
I put data in a tablix with row group, tablix1 in box1, tablix2 in box2.

Data will be listed in row in box1. the more row added, the tablix2 will be push down and won't fit the box2's possition.

Any solution, please?

Comment: try setting the report property "Consumer container whitespace" to True

Comment: There is a CanGrow property that you can set to False so the text box won't expand downward and truncate the text.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried change CanGrow of textbox. However, it still increase size after i insert Rectangle into that text box. The Tablix2 is pushed below still.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to make `CanGrow` property set to False